# Organize my data in Firestore Collections for best performance with Angular query

Tags: angular, database, performance, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up a new Google Firebase/Firestore db with world Countries(160), States(2500) and approx Cities (12K cities). I'll be using Angular to query them. Would the query perform faster if I had all the data in a single 'Collection', with each country being a document and then fields, or split the data out into 3 separate collections for Country, State and City.

Comment: Firestore will not perform inefficient queries without also prompting you to create an index.  If you run into that situation, the log will contain a link to the console where you can create that index.

Comment: What are the quries that you need to perform?